# Attach form-file to email, Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, file-upload

I need to get file from user and attach it to mail without saving it on server. Is this possible in Codeigniter to store uploaded file in variable and then attach it to email from Codeigniter email library? How to achieve that?
In CI I'm only finding classes to store uploaded files on hard drive not in variable.

Comment: what is the problem with? `$this->email->attach()` have you tried reading the whole documentation at http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html? where do you want the file to be saved? i think what you are trying to acheive cannot be done, when attaching something to a file you need to upload it first before attaching it on the email.

Comment: So i have to upload it, attach, send mail and then delete file from server?

Comment: Exactly, the sender (PHP) has to know the file's content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you have to upload the file to server directory then pass the name and path of file to email attach line i.e.,

```
    **$this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext');**
```

See the below code for upload class and email library.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

    $this->load->library('email');

    $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
    $this->email->to('someone@example.com');
    $this->email->cc('another@another-example.com');
    $this->email->bcc('them@their-example.com');

    $this->email->subject('Email Test');
    $this->email->attach('/path/to/file.ext');
    $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');

    $this->email->send();

    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid saving file on server?

Comment: No way. You can delete the file once email is sent by using unlink() function in php.

Comment: Then I'll do it your way :/

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html
```

It works well. I have tried this in my recent project

Comment: Problem is in uploading file to server without saving it on drive.